# How do I clean up Recent Changes on MediaWiki 1.31.1

Tags: mediawiki, user-generated-content

My Question is about Cleaning up MediaWiki Recent Changes
 
This question came from many MediaWiki website admins who have already asked this question all over the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a sub folder named cleanup in your website http web folder.
2. Install an older version of MediaWiki called MediaWiki 1.25.1. in the new folder you created named cleanup
3. Use the same mysql database username, password, and database name that you use
4. for your up to date MediaWiki installation.
5. Download and install MediaWiki Extension:RecentChangesCleanUp in the extensions folder found in the new folder you created called cleanup
6. Test out the extension page
7. and start cleaning up your MediaWiki installations Recent Changes.

Comment: I've removed the link to your youtube video.   Please do not create question and self-answer them with links to your own content.  It creates the appearance that you are asking and answering mostly for a link to your video on youtube.